# Iterate Twice in Map reduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I have written a Reducer job in which my key and value is composite . I have a requirement of iterating twice through the values and hence trying to cache the values but the same value is getting repeated. Please help me out.

Below is my Reducer class.

```
 public static class Reducerclass  extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
            DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss a");

            private MultipleOutputs<Text, Text> multipleOutputs;

            @Override
            public void setup(Context context){
                multipleOutputs = new MultipleOutputs<Text, Text>(context);
            }
            public void reduce(Text rkey, Iterable<Text> rvalue, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {             
                ArrayList<Text> ArrayList  = new ArrayList<Text>();
                Iterator<Text> iterator = rvalue.iterator();

                while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                    Text writable = iterator.next();
                    System.out.println("first iteration: " + writable);
                    ArrayList.add(new Text(writable));
context.write(new Text(rkey + ", "),new Text(writable + "--> first iteration"));
                }

                 int size = ArrayList.size();
                    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
                        System.out.println("second iteration: " + ArrayList.get(i));
context.write(new Text(rkey + ", "),new Text(ArrayList.get(i) + "--> Second iteration--->" + "Array Size -->" + size));
                    }


            }


        }
```

Input File:

```
1509075052824 13.0619798 80.1468367
1509075112825 13.07537311 80.19612851
1509073985114 13.0507832 80.25069245
1509075072824 12.91690859 80.06168244
```

Expected Output:

```
first iteration: 1509075052824 13.0619798 80.1468367
first iteration: 1509075112825 13.07537311 80.19612851
first iteration: 1509073985114 13.0507832 80.25069245
first iteration: 1509075072824 12.91690859 80.06168244

second iteration: 1509075052824 13.0619798 80.1468367
second iteration: 1509075112825 13.07537311 80.19612851
second iteration: 1509073985114 13.0507832 80.25069245
second iteration: 1509075072824 12.91690859 80.06168244
```

Current Output:

```
1509075042823 12.91877675 80.0466234--> first iteration
1509075042823 12.91877675 80.0466234--> Second iteration--->Array Size -->1
1509074972821 12.91738175 80.05294765--> first iteration
1509074972821 12.91738175 80.05294765--> Second iteration--->Array Size -->1
1509073795109 13.05561879 80.11920979--> first iteration
1509073795109 13.05561879 80.11920979--> Second iteration--->Array Size -->1
1509075132826 12.97988349 80.16310309--> first iteration
1509075132826 12.97988349 80.16310309--> Second iteration--->Array Size -->1
1509073885111 13.06640175 80.2457003--> first iteration
1509073885111 13.06640175 80.2457003--> Second iteration--->Array Size -->1
```

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: You're supposed to write to the Context, not the console

Comment: @cricket_007 I have updated the code.

Comment: @cricket_007 if you see the Array size on each line it print as 1. Can you please help me what am missing?

Comment: MapReduce is a distributed process. There isn't one reducer, so there is never one Arraylist.

Comment: To solve this problem how we can we achieve this, please guide me..

Comment: And if you did force everything down into one reducer (which must be done from the mapper). You're kinda defeating the point of using MapReduce at all

Comment: In what way we can iterate twice in Map reduce. I referred this site http://www.roman10.net/2012/08/13/hadoop-reducer-iterable-how-to-iterate-twice/

Comment: What about it? Your code is already like this. Print out the key, you'll see your problem more clearly

Comment: It would help to understand your objective here? What is it you need to achieve that requires iterating through all the values twice. Using a single key isn't a scalable approach.

Comment: i have to find the distance between two lat and log. **For ex:** in first row i have the lat and log as `12.91877675 80.0466234` and in second row i have the value `12.91738175 80.05294765`.In row1 find distance of row2,3,4 etc again row2 find distance between row1,2,3.. so on.. To achive this am iterating twice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the reducer all collected into one single Arraylist, you need one Reducer.

To get that, you need your Mapper to always output the same `rkey`

Answer (score 0):

I iterated it twice by mark the iterator first and then reset after the first iterates. the point is to use the `ReduceContext.ValueIterator`

```java
    ReduceContext.ValueIterator iterator = (ReduceContext.ValueIterator)rvalue.iterator();
      iterator.mark();//mark the first location
      //iterator the first time.
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       //do your things
      }
      //reset the iterator.
      iterator.reset();
      //iterator the second time.
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       //do your things
      }
```

after mark added, the task will output back_0_0.out at every next() called. The first iterate can't not clearMark, because the reset() need the mark. we can do this after the second iterator.

```java
    ReduceContext.ValueIterator iterator = (ReduceContext.ValueIterator)rvalue.iterator();
      iterator.mark();//mark the first location
      //iterator the first time.
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       //do your things
      }
      //reset the iterator.
      iterator.reset();
      //clearMark
      iterator.clearMark();
      //iterator the second time.
      while (iterator.hasNext()) {
       //do your things
      }

      //the Iterable class is the same with each key group, so we need to reset to clear the clearMarkFlag. and ignore the Exception to get it run.
      try{
          iterator.reset();
      }catch(Exception ignored){}
```